# CSS pseudo selector. Select last <p>

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

This is my code:

```
<section id="return-home-to">
   <div class="gutter">
    <h2 class="return-home-heading">
     Возвращайтесь в дом, свободный от хлопот
    </h2>

    <img src="img\icons\letter.png" alt="" class="icon" />
    <p>
     ПОЧТА ОТПРАВЛЕНА
    </p>

    <img src="img\icons\tape.png" alt="" class="icon" />
    <p>
     ОДЕЖДА И ОБУВЬ ОТРЕМОНТИРОВАНА
    </p>

    <img src="img\icons\lawn.png" alt="" class="icon" />
    <p>
     СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫЕ ЗАПРОСЫ
    </p>

    <img src="img\icons\dishes.png" alt="" class="icon" />
    <p id="last">
     ПОРЯДОК ДОМОВОГО: КРОВАТИ ЗАСТЕЛЕНЫ И ПОСУДА ПОМЫТА
    </p>

    <div class="info">
     <div class="triangle">
     </div>
     <div class="square">
      <a href="#">i</a>
     </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="sq-outline-btn">ПОРУЧИТЬ ЗАДАНИЯ</a>
   </div>
  </section>
```

I want to select last `<p>` (which has id="last") using a css pseudo selector "last-child" like this: `#return-home-to p:last-child {}`.

Question: What am I doing wrong? Why `#return-home-to p:last-child {}` does not select last `<p id="last">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `#return-home-to p:last-child {}` does not select last `<p id="last">`?

Nothing is selected because the last child isn't a `p` element.

In this case, the the last child of `#return-home-to` is an anchor element with the class `sq-outline-btn`, which explains why the `p` element isn't selected.

If you want to select the last element based on its *type*, use the [`:last-of-type` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead. As the name implies, it will select the last element of a specific type.

```
#return-home-to p:last-of-type {}
```